# Assign different colors to individual array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the array, arr1. I want to print this array (i.e. just display the numbers) but, I want to color the numbers based on their values. If arr1[i]<15, green, if  arr1[i]>20, red, else orange. Something to this effect.

```
var arr1 = [ 5,10,13,19,21,25,22,18,15,13,11,12,15,20,18,17,16,18,23,25,25,22,18,15,13,11,12,15,20,18];
```

Here is what I tried doing:

```
        for(var i=0; i<arr1.length;i++){
            if(arr1[i]<15){
                var temp = $(this).css("color","green");
                $this.text(temp);
            } else if(arr1[i]>20){
                var temp = $(this).css("color","red");
                $this.text(temp);
            } else {
                var temp = $(this).css("color","orange");
                $this.text(temp);
            }

        }
```

I tried changing the css property of individual elements and them adding them to the div, but it did not work for me.

Can someone suggest how should I go about doing this?

Comment: Please show the HTML for the numbers array.

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to in your code?

Comment: $(this) refers to the div inside which I want to display the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a `<span>` around the text and color that instead..

```
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length;i++){
    var value = arr1[i],
        element = $('<span/>',{'text':value}),
        color = '';

    if(value<15){
        color = 'green';
    } else if(value>20){
        color = 'red';
    } else {
        color = 'orange';
    }

    $this.append( element.css({'color':color}) );
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/6w7xL/

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
var arr1 = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 18],
    target = document.getElementById('test');

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    var elem = document.createElement('span'),
        text = document.createTextNode(arr1[i]);
    elem.appendChild(text);
    if (arr1[i] < 15) {
        elem.style.color = 'green'
    } else if (arr1[i] > 20) {
        elem.style.color = 'red'
    } else {
        elem.style.color = 'orange'
    }
    target.appendChild(elem);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KRduL/)

I'm using plain JavaScript because I couldn't see what `$(this)` was referring to, and it seemed easier to simply use a known variable to demonstrate.

And the reason I'm using a `span` to contain the text that's being assessed is simply because a `textNode` can't be styled directly, only an *element* can have a `style` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set css with jQuery directly on text nodes. It has to be on an element containing the text.